# create user input directory name in python

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a python script that takes 3 input arguments and creates a directory whose name is a concatenation of the 3 arguments. The command i give is python new.py user1 32 male and I should get a directory name created as user1_32_male, but I am getting directory name as user_name + "*" + age + "*" + gender. Can someone please correct my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import pylab as p
from math import *
from sys import argv
import os.path
import numpy as np
import os, sys
#print "Hello, Python!"

script, user_name, age, gender = argv

dirname = user_name + "_" + age + "_" + gender
newpath = r'./dirname'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Comment: Pick a type of quote (`"` or `'`) and use that. You're mixing both in the same expression and ending up with nonsense.

Comment: The string `r'./user_name + "_" + age + "_" + gender'` goes from single quote to single quote. If you don't want the other things inside the string, don't put them inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

You put the expression you want to *evaluate* to the directory name you want in quotes, so it doesn't get evaluated.  Try:

```
newpath = r'./' + user_name + "_" + age + "_" + gender
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I noticed that you're importing things more than once. There's no reason to import `os.path` since it's included in `os`. The same goes with `sys`.

It's easier to use string substitution in cases like this. The tuple that comes after the `%` contains values that are substituted into the `%s` in the part before the `%`.

```
from sys import argv
import os.path

script, user_name, age, gender = argv

newpath = '%s_%s_%s' % (user_name, age, gender)
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
```